# Restoring a BackWPup archive to a DigitalOcean WordPress Ubuntu 16.x Droplet?

Tags: mysql, restore, wordpress

I had a long-standing webhost go belly-up overnight... I have a backup of my WP site taken with BackWPup, and I'd like to host it on a DigitalOcean one-click Wordpress droplet. I selected the 16.x/4.7 droplet, and I'm having a devil of a time following [these instructions.](http://docs.backwpup.com/article/127-how-to-restore-a-wordpress-backup) (I have quite a bit of linux sysadmin experience, so I know my way around the command line, but I'm not as much as a webmaster/DBA as I'd need to be to cruise through this.)

The biggest problem is installing myphpadmin - I run the apt-get as per Digital Ocean's recommendation, but I'm unable to log in with "root" and the password I set.

Comment: Modern systems use `sudo`, rather than logging in as `root`. `sudo bash` is a Very Dangerous Workaround. Exit the `root` shell as soon as you can, preferably before testing (you want it to work for non-`root` users), AND before you typo yourself in the foot. Read `man sudo`.

Comment: @waltinator It's almost 2017. We're at the point where "sudo" is assumed to be there.

Comment: my interpretation of the question was that the "biggest problem" the OP has is that they can't access the root user account on the DBMS not the UNIX root account.